# Can I use sign "<-" in Content property of Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've tried to name `Button` like that:

```
<Button  Content="<-Delete" />
```

But I've seen the error:

> The token "  - Delete" is unexpected

How to include `<` sign in the `Content` property of `Button`?

Comment: Alternatively place the text in a resource file (*.resx).

Comment: @Greg  thanks. Can I use multilanguage if I use Resource File?

Comment: Yes, simply create multiple resx files, e.g. Messages.resx (default) and Messages.de.resx (German)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use :

```
<Button  Content="&lt;-Delete" />
```

Reference for [Use Special Characters in XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970677(v=vs.100).aspx)

[image]

Comment: @down-Voter : appreciate the spirit and thanks for the support. This is an open community not the Place to show Personal revenge.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
<Button Content="&lt;-Delete" />
```

or

```
<Button Content="&#60;-Delete" />
```

to accomplish this task.